# je ne veux pas que: "des" or "de"?

Tags: grammaire, articles, négation, subordonnées

I know what the translation is for "He doesn't read books":

> Il ne lit pas de livres.

But how about "I don't want him to read books"? Which of the following are correct?

> Je ne veux pas qu'il lise de livres.

> Je ne veux pas qu'il lise des livres.

> Je ne veux qu'il lise aucun livre.

> Je ne veux pas qu'il lise aucun livre.

> Je ne veux pas qu'il lise quel livre que ce soit.

Comment: Fun fact: my use of this sentence is inspired by Alain de Botton, of whom I am not a fan - but I recall that he once said to some journalist that he wouldn't want his children to have a deep desire to read, because such a deep desire to read would be a sign of anxiety.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

On peut dire : « Je ne veux pas qu’il lise de livres » et « Je ne veux pas qu’il lise des livres »

Mais il y a une nuance du sens de la négation.

Dans le premier cas, l’utilisation de « de », article partitif, pour indiquer que la négation est absolue. = je veux qu’il ne lise aucun livre.

Dans le deuxième cas, l’utilisation de l’article indéfini des marque une restriction, c’est à dire qu’il peut lire autre chose que des livres.

D’ailleurs il peut exister la même différence avec la première phrase :
Il ne lit pas de livres = il ne lit aucun livre.
Il ne lit pas des livres = il lit autre chose.

Answer (score 4):

- *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise de livres.* ✔
- *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise des livres.*  ✔ (→ *je veux probablement qu'il lise autre chose que des livres*)
- *Je ne veux qu'il lise aucun livre.* ✘ → *Je veux qu'il ne lise aucun livre.*
- *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise aucun livre.*  ✘  (double negation)
- *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise quel livre que ce soit.* ✘ → *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise quelque livre que ce soit* (too convoluted)

Comment: _Je ne veux pas qu'il lise **des** livres_  signifie aussi que je m'imagine ces livres, non ? Aussi, "des" est possible dans cette phrase, mais moins heureux, parce que la négation porte sur le verbe "veux".

Comment: @Oreste Si la personne pense à certains livres, elle dira *Je ne veux pas qu'il lise les livres* ou *qu'il lise ces livres*.